# Get temperature data from API key

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I am trying to get temperature data from api. I can't get it to work. What I am doing wrong? Do I need a v-for or something in the div where I show results?

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data () {
  return {
  api_key: 'adf173dfdcd1a6aea78ba12651a19177',
    base_url: 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/',
    weather: {},
    query: ''  
  }
   },
  methods: {
    grabWeather() {
        axios.get(`api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=${this.query}&appid=${this.api_key}`)
      .then(response => {
        this.weather = response.data;
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.20.0/axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Temperature:</h2>
  <input type="text" v-model="query">
  
 <div>
   {{weather.name}}
   {{weather.temp}}

 </div>
  <button @click="grabWeather">
  Grab
  </button>

</div>
```

Comment: You shouldn't include API keys in your posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I adjusted below items, then seems working fine.

1. feed full URL into `axios.get` like `${this.base_url}weather?`
2. not sure what `the parameter=id` of the query parameters means, I roughly read the user guide in **api.openweathermap.com** then change it to `q=${this.query}` (which will query the weather info by one city name).

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data () {
  return {
  api_key: 'adf173dfdcd1a6aea78ba12651a19177',
    base_url: 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/',
    weather: {},
    query: 'San Jose'  
  }
   },
  methods: {
    grabWeather() {
        axios.get(`${this.base_url}weather?q=${this.query}&appid=${this.api_key}`)
      .then(response => {
        this.weather = response.data;
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.20.0/axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Temperature:</h2>
  <input type="text" v-model="query">
  
 <div>
   <p>{{weather.name}}</p>
   <pre>{{weather.main}}</pre>

 </div>
  <button @click="grabWeather">
  Grab
  </button>

</div>
```